# Правильное обнаружение конца текста/файла при использовании потока

Tags: c++

Имеется текстовый файл, в котором следующим образом записаны цифры:

```
24
24000
2400
```

Во время чтения чисел с потока, достигнув последнего знака числа, необходимо вывести количество символов в данном числе.

Программа указывает для первого числа количество символов 2, для второго 5, а вот после последнего числа ничего не выводится. Почему?

Помогите найти ошибку...

Рабочий фрагмент кода:

```
while(input_file>>noskipws>>input_symbol){
    ...
    ...

    if(input_symbol!= ' ' && input_symbol!='\n' && input_symbol!='\0'&& input_symbol!='\r' &&  !input_file.eof()){

        num_size++;

    }

    if(input_symbol== ' ' || input_symbol=='\n' || input_symbol=='\0' || input_symbol=='\r' || input_file.eof()){

        cout << " String_size is " << num_size << endl;
        num_size=0;

    }
}
```

**Отдельная просьба для модераторов: пожалуйста, не корректируйте исходный код**

Comment: 1. В первом условии ИЛИ (`||`) совершенно не подходит. Представим, что текущий символ перевод каретки. Условие сработает, так как это не пробел (остальные условия даже не будут проверяться, потому что для ИЛИ этого достаточно). Там должно быть И (`&&`). Признак конца файла вообще не надо в этом if проверять, так как наличие конца файла не надо считать за подходящий символ.

Comment: 2. Если нужно количество символов в строке, то где в алгоритме num_size обнуляется, после завершения строки ? (я вижу что оно зачем то еще раз увеличивается)

Comment: Да, там была опечатка с num_size. Оно конечно же обнуляется. Остальное тоже подправил. Но не сработало.

Comment: А входной файл создан в редакторе какой ОС ? Если whindows, то там перевод каретки два символа `\r`, `\n`. Если linux/unix то '\n'. А в MaxOS вообще один `\r`. Вообще если сказано что на входе цифры, вот цифры бы я и считал, для надежности, т.е. `input_symbol >= '0' && input_symbol <='9'`

Comment: Добавил \r. Тоже, к сожалению, не помогло. Условие проверки цифр выполняется до этого кода.

Comment: А зачем читать символы? Читайте как слово, всех проблем... `string s; while(input_file>>s) { cout << s.size() << endl; }`

Comment: Этот вопрос - контекст другой задачи. Дело в том, что мне как раз необходимо ответить именно на него. То есть чтение слова таким образом, каким вы советуете, не решит вопроса.